# If element has children html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I the following un-ordered list.

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <a class="hlink hlink-1" href="#"> Prank Boss Apps </a>
        <ul> 
          <li> <a href="#"> link 1 </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> link 2 </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> link 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="hlink hlink-2" href="#"> Uninstall an app.  </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="hlink hlink-3" href="#"> Contact Us </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

In the un-ordered list, not every list-item will have another un-ordered list.

```
          <li> <a href="#"> blah </a>
            <ul> 
              <li> <a href="#"> link 1 </a></li>
              <li> <a href="#"> link 2 </a></li>
              <li> <a href="#"> link 3 </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

So some will just have a link inside of the list item and others will have a un-ordered list inside.

How can I check if the list item doesn't have another un-ordered list inside of it?

Comment: At what point do you want to check. Will it be in response to a click? Which element are you attaching the handler to?

Answer (score 3):

```
 function hasChildULs(thisList)
 {    
      if ($(thisList).children('ul').length > 0)
      {
           return true;
      }
      else
      {
           return false;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Tiny optional optimization: for non-negative integers (which `length` always is) doing `if (foo > 0)` is the same as simply `if (foo)`, since `0` is a non-truthy value and all others are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've got a reference to the li element you can use this.

```
function isLeafNode(liElement) {
   return !liElement.getElementsByTagName("ul").length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_element.asp (if you don't want to use jQuery)

Comment: w3schools is occasionally inaccurate and often provides poor examples. I'd recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element instead.